# Compare array and keep only true value

Tags: php, arrays

I got a array of true/false values like this

```
$bools = array(
    0 => true,
    1 => false,
    2 => true,
    3 => true,
    4 => false
);
```

and another array or value like

```
$names = array(
    0 => 'joe',
    1 => 'bob',
    2 => 'steve',
    3 => 'mario',
    4 => 'george'
);
```

What I need, is to get a return array (in PHP) that contain ONLY the true value from array 2 compared to array 1. so the final array will be:

```
$result = array(
    0 => 'joe',
    1 => 'steve',
    2 => 'mario'
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research to try to get to your goal?

Comment: 1. go to google
2. write php array_map()
3. read manual
4. write code and resolve problem
5. go back and say thanks

Comment: I try it with counter, and foreach loop, but i got confuse !

Comment: @menardmam Show your effort in your question. So we see where you got stuck and can show you how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine the arrays:

```
array_combine( $names, $bools );
```

this will result in:

```
array (
  joe => true, 
  bob => false, 
  steve => true, 
  mario => true, 
  george => false)
```

Then, extract the wanted names with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$result = array_keys( array_combine( $names, $bools ), true );
```

This will only return keys which have the value `true`:

```
$result = array(
    0 => 'joe',
    1 => 'steve',
    2 => 'mario'
);
```

Comment: Beautiful, simple, one liner. Code is art !

Comment: The only restriction here worth to note is, that every element can only occur once in the array, since they are used as key in the process.

Answer (score 3):

First you can filter out all false values from your first array with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). So you will end up with an array containing all keys which you want to keep in the other array.

Then you can use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to get the intersection of keys from your second array and the filtered first array, e.g.

```
$result = array_intersect_key($arrayTwo, array_filter($arrayOne));
```

Comment: Yes and if he needs to reindex the array use `array_values` function

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, i have write code for example only. Customize it with your requirement.

```
$a = array (true,false,true,true,false);    
$b = array ('one','two','three','four','five');
$c = array();
for ( $i=0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++) {
   if ( $a[$i] == 'true' ){
       $c[$i] = $b[$i];   //store output values into another array
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a = [true,false,true,true,false];
 $b = ['bob','jiw','mow','moe','windy'];
 $final_arr = array();
 foreach($a as $k => $v){
    if($v)$final_arr[] = $b[$k];
 }
 print_r($final_arr);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with the basic `foreach()` loop:

```
$bools = array(
    0 => true,
    1 => false,
    2 => true,
    3 => true,
    4 => false
);

$names = array(
    0 => 'joe',
    1 => 'bob',
    2 => 'steve',
    3 => 'mario',
    4 => 'george'
);

$yourArr = array();
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    if($bools[$key] == true){
        $yourArr[] = $value; // store required values in your required array
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourArr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => joe
    [1] => steve
    [2] => mario
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = array_filter(array_combine($keys, $values));
```

Comment: With `$keys` being the names array and `$values` being the true/false array it works with an added `array_keys()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 `array_combine` will make an associative array (joe => true, bob => false, steve => true, mario => true, george => false) and `array_filter` will drop elements with false values.

Answer (score -1):

```
$bools = array(
    true,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    true,
);
$names = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
);
$result = array_values(array_intersect_key($names, array_filter($bools)));
dumpr($result);
```

Results in:

```
array(3) {
    [0] = string(1) "a"
    [1] = string(1) "b"
    [2] = string(1) "e"
}
```

Comment: anyway u used wrong order of parameters, till someone already posted same thing with better explanation